# POST requests from grunt-connect-proxy plugin do not contain data

Tags: php, angularjs, post, gruntjs

It works so far that Angular can make a POST request to my local running Apache server. From that server, I return a Symfony JsonResponse object:

```
$http.post("/api", {"foo":"bar"})
          .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              $scope.data = data;
              console.log(data);
          }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              $scope.status = status;
          });
```

Now I am stuck with the fact that it only returns `[]`. If I return a hardcoded associative array,  it works.

What could be the problem? ([plugin](https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the solution was to check for `content_type:application/json` because the $_POST will not get populated if it is set.
Angular automaticly does this.

If you don't know this, it is looking for a needle in a haystack.
In that regard, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-make-angular-js-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload?rq=1) was extremely helpfull. and following that I stumbled on [this page](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/json_request_body.html)

this line did it

```
if(0 === strpos($request->headers->get('CONTENT_TYPE'), 'application/json')){
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting `[]` as data on success, this means your server is giving empty response, thought still a valid response. Try running your API in browser(or better use POSTMAN plugin in Chrome) to check if the same API call is returning `[]` as a response.

Comment: I use it, but I get the same result

Comment: That means your server is sending response as []. I dont see any problem with Angular, the problem is on server side.

Comment: For some reason Apache/php cannot parse the posted variables? that will be my next google search or the plugin is not passing them. Maybe, I can use wireshark to see what is being send? does that work on your own computer?